# Parameterized JUnit tests with non-primitive parameters?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, parameterized

There is a nice possibility to run JUnit test with parameters where the same test method is executed multiple times with different data as described here: http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html

Unfortunately, it only seems possible to use primitive parameters or Strings, but not objects. Is there any workaround known for this?

Comment: Did you figure out any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 9):

The type of the `data()` method in the use of the [@Parameters](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests) annotation is `List<Object[]>`, so you can put in any object.

To pass in, e.g., a `Money` object, your array to be converted to a list would be:

> { { new Money(26, "CHF") },
>     { new Money(12, "USD") } }

The constructor of the test class should take a Money object as argument then.

Answer (score 1):

recently i started [zohhak](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak) project. it lets you write:

```java
@TestWith({
   "25 USD, 7",
   "38 GBP, 2",
   "null,   0"
})
public void testMethod(Money money, int anotherParameter) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using object is also possible using Junit `@Parameters`.

**Example:-**

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TestParameter {

@Parameter(value=0)
public int expected;

@Parameter(value=1)
public int first;

@Parameter(value=2)
public int second;
private Calculator myCalculator;


@Parameters(name = "Test : {index} : add({1}+{2})= Expecting {0}")//name will be shared among all tests
public static Collection addNumbers() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Integer[][] { { 3, 2, 1 }, { 5, 2, 3 }, { 9, 8, 1 }, { 200, 50, 150 } });
}
@Test
public void testAddWithParameters() {
    myCalculator = new Calculator();
    System.out.println(first + " & " + second + " Expected = " + expected);
    assertEquals(expected, myCalculator.Add(first, second));
}
```

}